# How to add a form in $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mddialog

How to add a form in $mdDialog and on submit how to send to email. I am trying to get the from in the dialog but couldn't get any clue of it.

My controller is:

```
App.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
console.log("reaching mainController");
$scope.showPrompt = function (ev) {
    console.log("reaching showprompt");
    // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
    var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
        .title('Please give us your details')
        .textContent('We are happy to quote for your interiors in your new home.')
        .placeholder('Name')
        .ariaLabel('Dog name')
        .initialValue('')
        .placeholder('Name')
        .ariaLabel('Dog name')
        .initialValue('')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('Submit')
        .cancel('Later');

    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function (result) {
        $scope.status = 'You decided to name your dog ' + result + '.';
    }, function () {
        $scope.status = 'You didn\'t name your dog.';
    });
};
```

I wanted to show the dialog in the page load and i have added the function in ng-init

```
    <div ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="showPrompt($event)">
```

The modal is loading promptly on the load time. Am i going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Im not sure if I fully understood what you wanna do, but you shouldn be using ng-init; You should execute the function right after the declaration in the controller: $scope.showPrompt();

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use "templateUrl" there you can put the url of your html file and do what ever you want or use "template" for inline html.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

```
$mdDialog.show({
          targetEvent: $event,
          template:
            '<md-dialog>' +

            '  <md-dialog-content>Hello {{ employee }}!</md-dialog-content>' +

            '  <md-dialog-actions>' +
            '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
            '      Close Greeting' +
            '    </md-button>' +
            '  </md-dialog-actions>' +
            '</md-dialog>',
          controller: 'GreetingController',
          onComplete: afterShowAnimation,
          locals: { employee: $scope.userName }
        });
```